# How to set a fixed size background gradient?

Tags: flutter

I have a screen with slivers and textfields, i drawn one gradient in the background, it´s ok! But when i click on the textfield, the keyboard modify the size of background. How can i prevent this?

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.white],
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight),
            ),
          ),
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                floating: true,
                snap: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0.0,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    title: const Text("Test"), centerTitle: true),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Test Keyboard"),
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Test Keyboard"),
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Test Keyboard"),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Before click on TextField]
[image: After click on TextField]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to set in scaffold the property resizeToAvoidBottomPadding to false.

Answer (score 2):

If you still need to have the `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` (or `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`) property to true, for example to avoid to obscure TextFields with the keyboard, you can use a solution like the following in order to avoid the shrinking of a gradient background like yours:

```
Container(
        height: screenHeight,
        decoration: getGradientDecoration(context), // your gradient decoration
        child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, 
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                  // your form body (text fields, ...)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
        )
)
```

This lets the inner Scaffold to resize its content, but since the Container with the gradient background is outside the Scaffold, it doesn't get resized and the gradient remains consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get this done is to use a fixed size container. Use media query to get your width and height and set your container size to those dimensions.

```
var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Container(
  width: screenWidth,
  height: screenHeight,
  ...
)
```

Comment: @FelipeK I did the exact same thing my side and it works. What's the result? Can you change your gradient to have three colors so that you can see if it's actually shrinking the background gradient.

Comment: The same problem occurs, the keyboard and the floating button are positioned above the keyboard, and the gradient changes, I was only able to force the gradient size by setting that "resizeToAvoidBottomPadding" property of the scaffold to false. Maybe that floating button that i included after can had affect.

Comment: @FelipeK I see. That's default behaviour for the floating button, I don't think you'd want to change that. You'll add another touch between the user and pressing that button. But it's your call. Sorry I couldn't help, it works my side, unless your Test widget is in a widget that resizes when a keyboard comes up, any kind of scrollable widget then I can't see exactly what the problem is.Goodluck

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you put the CustomScrollView as a child of the container?